# Enable full-screen mode for applications on Lion

Tags: macos, terminal, fullscreen

There some applications which I can not yet run in full-screen mode. I particularly would need the OSX Terminal app and possible the TextEdit. However, after the upgrade they remained the same, and does not have the full screen button in the top right corner. How can I enable Lion style full-screen mode for there applications?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another terminal like application is iterm2. It goes fullscreen and works extremely well!(a lot better than terminal)

http://www.iterm2.com/#/section/home

Comment: I second iTerm2 as a Terminal.app replacement, but as regard to the original question both Terminal as iTerm2 support Lion fullscreen mode.

Comment: Although you did not answer directly my question, your answer solved my issue. iTerm looks great.

Answer (score 8):

Lion's Terminal.app does support fullscreen mode. Maybe you are overlooking it? How did you upgrade?

As for TextEdit, applications need to explicitely implement Lion fullscreen support, and this has not been done for TextEdit. There are other 3rd party text editors that have implemented fullscreen mode, depending on what usage you have for a text-editor.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But strangely my terminal does not have the maximizer.. and I do have Lion.

Answer (score 3):

Terminal does support Full Screen on Mac OS X Lion. It sounds like you’re opening an older version of Terminal. Check **Terminal > About Terminal** to see what version you’re using.  It should be 2.2 or later.

You can see the location of the Terminal you’re using by Command-Clicking on the Terminal icon in the Dock. That will reveal the Terminal application in Finder. It should be in `/Applications/Utilities/Terminal` on your startup volume.

Comment: You’re welcome. For the benefit of others, what exactly was wrong? Did you have an old Terminal marked “Keep in Dock”?

Comment: Yes, this was the issue, and I did not realize that Terminal appeared under Utilities. Now I switched to iTerm2, however. It seems to be a more powerful tool than the original terminal.